# BillingProcessor.isSubscribed(product_id) is always returning true

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am using BillingProcessor for in-app billing of some subscriptions. A user can avail free trial for 3 days on first time subscription. If the user has unsubscribed and the trial period ends `BillingProcessor.isSubscribed(product_id)` should return false but I'm always getting true. I have also tried `BillingProcessor.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()` to refresh the cache but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering to my own question.

I couldn't resolve this problem. BillingProcessor was not providing my updated information about subscriptions. I had to clear Google Play Services cache or reboot the phone to get the updates about in app subscriptions.

I found another wrapper for In App Billing Service and it worked without any problem. The wrapper and information about how to use it, can be found at 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive

Comment: Actually I do have problems with the trivialdrive- application too.. have you resolved it somehow different?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. TrivialDrive worked perfectly for me.